# Call function from superclass with different this

Tags: typescript

I have Owner class, Animal (which might have an owner), Dog (which extends Animal) and a type WithOwner which makes sure that animal has an owner:

```
type WithOwner<T extends Animal> = T & {
    owner: NonNullable<T["owner"]>;
};
class Owner {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class Animal {
    owner?: Owner;

    ownership(this: WithOwner<Animal>): string {
        return this.owner.name;
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    override ownership(this: WithOwner<Dog>): string {
        return super.ownership() + " owns a dog";
    }
}
```

However I get an error on `super.ownership()`: `TS2684: The 'this' context of type 'Animal' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'WithOwner<Animal>'.`. For some reason TS compiler forgets that inside this function animal has an owner.

Any ideas what's going on here and how to fix it? I tried adding `if (this.owner)` before `super` but it still didn't help.

Comment: How would you call `Animal::ownership` normally? I mean how do you supply `this` that satisfies `WithOwner<Animal>`?

Comment: May I ask out of curiosity why you want to override `this`? Seems like that could be a source of strange behavior in the future ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually don't understand how you would call `Animal::ownership` so that it satisfies `WithOwner<Animal>`. "Normally" that will never work, as `owner` is optional on `Animal`. You could use `Animal::ownership::call` and pass `this`. Something along those lines:

```js
class Dog extends Animal {
    override ownership(this: WithOwner<Dog>): string {
        return super.ownership.call(this) + " owns a dog";
    }
}
```

I've never really heard of overwriting `this` but to me it makes sense that `super::ownership` is basically "uncallable" without supplying a different `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that JavaScript (and typescript) `this` is implicit supplied to a function, if you want a parameter, don't call it `this`.

[see this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgeQO4DsICcA8AVKCAD2AnQBMBnKAQXTgFsBDAGwD4oBeKAgMigDeAWABQUcVAD2GbAC4oAOUnoFAVxYsmAIxYR8AbQBE0zFkMBdNgG5RAXxsiAxpsrU0pwaIlR0TBhHlKYCw4dABzB29HZSCsVUdgSSwACl9-QODQsIBKTzFvCSQ4SgA6NOhucsiJWztRZyZXWnpmFjzvE2wAfnl3bAcvCU6sSkQ4MGSieXgkPtw6RlY2bIyQ8KgAHyhVCggAM1CIcnaC8SwIYFUsdCgi0uGusr8IavFakXf6l2oAEUkwwgkMhUZqLNrCfLiSQAN2wIXI0GGo3Gk2mCBQMlwfzCy1WWROp3Ol2uUEoqkgWBKSLGEyIuQA1FBDFIMNQmFByP9DK8oO9bEA)

also [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: I'm aware, but typescript also allows overriding what `this` is expected to be inside the function (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function). I'm aware that `this` in this case isn't a parameter, but what I want to do is to only allow calling `ownership` if `owner` is set on the Animal/Dog.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This works:

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    override ownership(this: WithOwner<Dog>): string {
        return super.ownership.call(this) + " owns a dog";
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need `as WithOwner<Animal>` as `Dog extends Animal`.

Comment: Good point, I don't know why I thought I would, thanks.